# Working with django and react application with webpack-dev-server (Hot-reloading). I am getting this error in console. But my page is loading fine

Tags: python, django, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

main-8f0497ba1ebedd971dd2.js:6

[WDS] Disconnected!
close @ main-8f0497ba1ebedd971dd2.js:6
(anonymous) @ main-8f0497ba1ebedd971dd2.js:1
r.dispatchEvent @ main-8f0497ba1ebedd971dd2.js:6
(anonymous) @ main-8f0497ba1ebedd971dd2.js:6

```
**webpack.config.js**

var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
     './react/index',
        ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./project_fashion/static/bundle/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/bundle/',
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [


        { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader',exclude: /node_modules/, },
        { test: /\.jsx$/, use: 'babel-loader',exclude: /node_modules/, },
        { test: /\.css$/,  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],exclude: /node_modules/, },
        { test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, use: 'url-loader',exclude: /node_modules/, },


    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }

};


**server.js**

var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000')
})

**Settings.py** 

"""
Django settings for project_fashion project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'x!#fobhlo+n(f@yczw0n^u6bj+v(2)68tc(hgl1r07&b0lg-jq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

#ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader',
    'corsheaders',
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/bundle/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_fashion.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'project_fashion/template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_fashion.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/project_fashion/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
import os
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'project_fashion' "/static/"),
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=[
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8a2o.png)